# EndEditing/ResignFirstResponder from UIContainerView EXC_BAD_ACCESS SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, keyboard

When calling either `self.view.endEditing(true or false)`, `self.parentViewController?.view.endEditing(true or false)` or `textField.resignFirstResponder()`.

My app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

I am calling from a `UIContainerView` and have tried calling from the `parentViewController`, all with the same result.

Any suggestions/solutions would be great

Thanks

Comment: The parameter for endEditing is of type NSText, isn't it?

Comment: No, it is true or false (bool) wether it should force or not

Comment: Well, this is what I get on auto completion: `let v = NSTextField(); v.endEditing(<#textObj: NSText#>)`

Comment: Oops. I need a coffee. You're talking about IOS stuff :-[